# System.ObjectDisposedException on a socket and when to close streams

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, out-of-memory, objectdisposedexception

I'm trying to code a client-server communication. So far, i manage to connect in a first thread. A second thread read the socket and a third one check if there is no unexpected disconection from a client.

My problem is that i got a System.ObjectDisposedException when i try to read the socket. If i continue the running of the program (ignoring the exception), the same exception happens when i check if the socket is still connected.

The server is a class with the following fields :

```
static class Server
    {
        static ArrayList readList = new ArrayList();
        static ArrayList acceptList = new ArrayList();

        static public Thread thread1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(SocketConnector));

        static Thread thread2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(SocketListener));
        static Thread thread3 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(SocketClose));
        static Thread thread4 = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(SocketWriter));
```

readList is used in the socket reader thread (last sample of code in this message)
acceptList contains the results of Socket.Accept(). Here is how acceptList is filled.

```
 static void SocketConnector()
    {
     while (true)
     {
      sock.Listen(25);
      actif = sock.Accept();

      if (actif != null)
        {
          lock (acceptList)
            {
              acceptList.Add(actif);
              Console.WriteLine("IT WORKS");
              // that writeline appeared when i try to connect with the client.
            }
              actif = null;
        }
    }
```

Now here is how i check if there wasn't any unexpected disconnection from the client :

```
            static void SocketClose()
            {
             while (true)
             {
                for (int i = 0; i < acceptList.Count; ++i)
                {
                    if (((Socket)acceptList[i]).Poll(25, SelectMode.SelectRead) && ((Socket)acceptList[i]).Available == 0)
                    {


                           lock (acceptList)
                            { 
                               ((Socket)acceptList[i]).Close();
                                Console.WriteLine("Client " + ((Socket)acceptList[i]).GetHashCode() + " déconnecté");
                                acceptList.Remove((Socket)acceptList[i]);
                                i--;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    Thread.Sleep(5);
            }
```

And the last part of code i need to show if how i read my socket.

```
    static void SocketListener()
    { 
            while (true)
            {
                readList.Clear();
                lock (acceptList)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < acceptList.Count; i++)
                    {
                        readList.Add((Socket)acceptList[i]);
                    }
                }
                if (readList.Count > 0)
                {
                    Socket.Select(readList, null, null, 1000);

                    for (int i = 0; i < readList.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (((Socket)readList[i]).Available > 0)
                        {
                            while (((Socket)readList[i]).Available > 0)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Debut Deserialisation");

                                // get the underlying socket for the TcpClient
                                TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
                                client.Client = (Socket)readList[i];
                                NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream();
                                BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(ns);
                                Message received = new Message();

                                Console.WriteLine(received.msg);
                                Console.WriteLine(received.user);
                                Console.WriteLine(received.targetChatroom);


                               // Deserialisation
                                int length = reader.ReadInt32();
                                byte[] msgArray = reader.ReadBytes(length);
                                received.msg = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(msgArray);

                                length = reader.ReadInt32();
                                msgArray = reader.ReadBytes(length);
                                received.user = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(msgArray);

                                length = reader.ReadInt32();
                                msgArray = reader.ReadBytes(length);
                                received.targetChatroom = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(msgArray);

                               ns.Close();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

I realised that maybe my socket was closed by the line ns.Close(), and that cause the error. With ns.Close(), I just attempted to close the stream I created to get the datas from the socket, and not close the socket itself. I tried to remove that ns.Close() line, and the ObjectDisposedException doesn't appear anymore ! However, now i got an OutOfMemoryException at the line :

```
byte[] msgArray = reader.ReadBytes(length);
```

in the reading thread. I believe this exception is caused because the stream isn't closed.

EDIT : The OutOfMemoryException comes from code in the client. Problem solved here.

The disconnection detection works, and the deserialization too.

My question is : When should i close that stream ??

Comment: A lot of code but still incomplete. It's unclear on which thread(s) this runs and `new Thread(new ThreadStart(SocketClose));` doesn't look like a great tool. Your reading thread should cooperate in stopping and closing.

Comment: @Henk Holterman You're right. I editted to show which code sample belongs to which thread. The 'SocketClose' thread is a thread that check if the socket is still connected if the other host doesn't send you a packet when it disconnects (e.g. because it disconnected ungracefully). Maybe the name isn't really well chosen.

Answer (score 0):

When using `Socket.Select`, there's really no need for an additional thread - just include the sockets in the `checkError` parameter as well as in the `checkRead` parameter.

It might look like the disconnection bit works, because during your test it closed your socket, but my guess is that the remote connection actually sent a valid disconnect (as opposed to an "unexpected" disconnect) message, causing your read thread to choke on the now closed socket.

You should expect any operation on a `Socket` to throw a `SocketException` for unexpected errors, *and* expect a message of exactly 0 bytes for a regular disconnect.

I don't use `BinaryReader` that much but I'd expect it to throw an `EndOfStreamException` at `int length = reader.ReadInt32();`.